# How read paragraph using PDFBox in Android

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

Since PdfBox was not working in android (because it uses some AWT components that are not supported on Android). Someone suggested this to me on this site. So, I used [TomRoush/PdfBox-Android](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android)

Now I read pdf like this

```
public void readPdf(File pdfFile) {

    try {
        PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(getApplicationContext());

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
        PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        stripper.setStartPage(1);
        String text = stripper.getText(document);
        Log.d("location", text);


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("location", e.toString());
    }

}
```

But this gives me the whole PDF as a `String`. What I want is a string for each paragraph or article.

Comment: PDFs do not necessarily have a notion of paragraphs or articles. They actually do not necessarily know lines. PDFBox text extraction puts together lines by their **y** coordinate (look out for line break characters in the returned string).

Comment: have you tried setParagraphStart and setParagraphEnd? PDFText2HTML shows how to use it.